# Hibernate can't create a table with @ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I created a table of "User" which is perfectly created by hibernate, no problem on this one. The problem is on my second model (an entity called "Character") which is a model with a `@ManyToOne` relation, I don't know why but hibernate can't create this second table.

My server is a MySql instance with AWS RDS. The first table is created by hibernate but not the second.

```java
@Entity
public class Character {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private User joueur;
    private String pseudo;
    private Integer points;

    public Character() {
        super();
    }

    public Character(User joueur) {
        // appel a l'autre constructeur
        this(joueur, null, null);
    }

    public Character(User joueur, String pseudo,Integer points) {
        super();
        this.joueur = joueur;
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPseudo() {
        return pseudo;
    }

    public void setPseudo(String pseudo) {
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
    }

    public Integer getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(Integer points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public User getJoueur() {
        return joueur;
    }

}

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "joueur")
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    private List<Character> personnages;
    private String league;
    private Integer points; 

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Character> getPersonnages() {
        return personnages;
    }

    public void setPersonnages(List<Character> personnages) {
        this.personnages = personnages;
    }

    public String getLeague() {
        return league;
    }

    public void setLeague(String league) {
        this.league = league;
    }

    public Integer getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(Integer points) {
        this.points = points;
    }  
}

@Controller   
@RequestMapping(path="/init")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
               // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private CharacterRepository characterRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
    public String addNewUser () {

        User joueur = new User();
        joueur.setUsername("testUser");
        joueur.setPassword("password");
        joueur.setLeague("Bronze");
        joueur.setPoints(10000);
        userRepository.save(joueur);

        Character perso = new Character(joueur,"testPerso1",1000);
        characterRepository.save(perso);

        return "";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I have this error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character add constraint Kdf2yvyvitaqt2u7de3ywfjcv foreign key (joueur_id) refe' at line 1

Comment: Have a feeling your MySQL server still defaults into creating MyISAM tables instead of using InnoDB as table engines

Comment: Then why did it suceed to create a table of user and to save them ?

Comment: I think the problem is a my annotation @ManyToOne
private User joueur; i don't know why this doesn't work

Comment: I very much doubt that you said you have a MySQL syntax error.. i think you should look to a way in the framework to add/change a table engine for MySQL

Comment: In application properties the way in the framework to add/change a table engine for MySQL is to set "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update" , I try to change to create but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution ... JPA annotation fordid the name of the table 'Character", just change the name of the table and it will work perfectly, stupid JPA ...